# awk: change field separator keeping first column as is

Tags: regex, awk, field

I have an `in.csv` file with just one column in this fashion:

```
Sample
a_b_c
d_e_f
g_h_i
```

I want to change the field separator from `_` to `,` and print the separate fields, but keeping the input column as is in the first column of the output file. I want to use `awk` in principle.

This is what I have so far:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS="_";OFS=","} {$1=$1}1' in.csv > out.csv
```

which gives me this

```
Sample
a,b,c
d,e,f
g,h,i
```

How can I output it like this instead, preserving the original column (renamed `ID`)?

```
ID,group1,group2,group3
a_b_c,a,b,c
d_e_f,d,e,f
g_h_i,g,h,i
```

Note that input number of fields is variable, and the input `Sample` line might be other name, or be empty, or even non-existent, but I would still want the output like that...

**EDIT**

After checking all the answers, I have to clarify here the input file above is just an example... the real files I have usually have more than 3 fields separated by `_` (but I do not know how many beforehand) and countless lines, however I will try to make sure all the rows in a given file are consistent on the number of fields to "split".

The answers below do not seem to work when my files have more or less than exactly 3 fields to split per row, I would need a more universal one-liner if that is possible.

For the moment, to keep things simple, I'd rather not do anything to the header line and leave it as is.

This means that for this other example:

```
Some_header
a_b_c_1
d_e_f_2
g_h_i_3
```

I would like to obtain this:

```
Some_header
a_b_c_1,a,b,c,1
d_e_f_2,d,e,f,2
g_h_i_3,g,h,i,3
```

Optimally, the one-liner should deal with cases where there are rows with inconsistent fields, so from a file like this:

```
Some_header
a_b_c
d_e_f_2
g_h_i_3_4
```

I would like to obtain this:

```
Some_header
a_b_c,a,b,c
d_e_f_2,d,e,f,2
g_h_i_3_4,g,h,i,3,4
```

Isn't there a way to record the row with the `_` in a variable, then split the variable by `_`, and then print the variable and all its components separated by `,`? Sorry I thought this would be easier... Maybe it would be easier with a `Perl` one-liner? Sorry not so proficient with one-liners... Thanks again!

Comment: `preserving the original column (renamed ID)` So preserved or renamed?

Comment: preserved as is with different header (but can still be the same header)

Comment: checkout the `split()` function. `split($0,"_",array);print $0","a[0],a[1],a[2]`

Comment: Please check my EDIT

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could you please try following, written and tested on shown samples only. This should work with any number of fields too tested it in https://ideone.com/fWgggq

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS="_"
  OFS=","
  print "ID,group1,group2,group3"
}
FNR>1{
  val=$0
  $1=$1
  print val,$0
}'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                   ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{                                  ##Starting BEGIN section of program from here.
  FS="_"                                ##Setting field separator as _ here,
  OFS=","                               ##Setting OFS as comma here.
  print "ID,group1,group2,group3"       ##Printing header as per OP requirement here.
}
FNR>1{                                  ##Checking condition if this is greater than 1st line then do following.
  val=$0                                ##Store current line into var val here.
  $1=$1                                 ##reassign first field to itself so that new OFS which is , is implemented to whole line.
  print val,$0                          ##Printing current new line here.
}'  Input_file                          ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: for some reason, this works for the example file with 3 fields (like `a_b_c`), but the moment there are more fields (like `a_b_c_d`) or less fields (like `a_b`), it does not work...

Comment: Please check my EDIT

Comment: @DaniCee, hi, my solution is NOT hatdcoded it will work with your any number of fields please check this which I tested in URL https://ideone.com/fWgggq

Comment: OK it works, my files had DOS file ending instead of UNIX, I had to run `dos2unix` on the files first, and now the `awk` one-liner works as expected... weird though

Comment: @DaniCee, your welcome happy to help, thanks for sharing that you fixed it with dos2unix cheers and happy learning on SO :)

Answer (score 4):

Another one which, however, does not deal with the header line (atm anyway, left as an exercize etc.):

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
    FS="_"                                # set delimiters
    OFS=","
}
{
    for(i=0;i<=NF;i++)                    # loop from 0 to get $0
        printf "%s%s",$i,(i==NF?ORS:OFS)  # print dealing with OFS and EOL
}' file
```

Output:

```
Sample,Sample
a_b_c,a,b,c
d_e_f,d,e,f
g_h_i,g,h,i
```

Yet another one which does deal with *different input files with variable number of groups* picking the header count from the first data record (`NR==2`):

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
    FS="_"                                # set delimiters
    OFS=","
}
NR>=2 {                                   # process only data records, not header
    if(NR==2)                             # create the header
        for(i=0;i<=NF;i++)
            printf "%s%s",(i==0?"ID":"group" i),(i==NF?ORS:OFS)
    for(i=0;i<=NF;i++)                    # loop from 0 to get $0
        printf "%s%s",$i,(i==NF?ORS:OFS)  # print dealing with OFS and ORS
}' file
```

Output:

```
ID,group1,group2,group3
a_b_c,a,b,c
d_e_f,d,e,f
g_h_i,g,h,i
```

And finally a short one using GNU awk:

```
$ awk '$0=$0 (gensub(/(^|_)/,",","g"))' file
```

Comment: for some reason, this works for the example file with 3 fields (like `a_b_c`), but the moment there are more fields (like `a_b_c_d`) or less fields (like `a_b`), it does not work...

Comment: Please check my EDIT

Comment: OK it works, my files had DOS file ending instead of UNIX, I had to run `dos2unix` on the files first, and now the `awk` one-liner works as expected... weird though

Comment: If you're using GNU awk (or mawk or Busybox awk) you could set `RS="\r\n"` or `RS="\r?\n"`

Answer (score 2):

I don't see a reason to change FS. Just print what you want to actually print, instead of `{$1=$1}1` using some default `awk` behavior.

```
awk '
   BEGIN {FS="_"; OFS=","}
   NR==1{print "ID,group1,group2,group3"}
   NR!=1{print $0, $1, $2, $3}
'
```

Comment: the problem is I have different input files with variable number of groups... I want exactly like your answer but extended to all cases if possible. So it would be print `group` +`1:n` where `n` is the number of groups. and then print `$0` and all the group fields

Comment: @DaniCee Is the variable an input parameter, or do you want to derive it from the header, or from the data rows?  Is it constant per input file? (ie, will all the rows be consistent?)

Comment: in principle all the rows would be consistent yes, and it would be derived from the resulting number of fields after "splitting" by `_`

Comment: I don't really want it to be a really complicated solution, what I have done so far is use the one-liner in my question and then add the column from `in.csv` as a column in `out.csv` using Excel (changing the header names manually)... just wondering whether this could be easily implemented

Comment: Actually, to keep it simple, probably better to not deal with the headers at all, just start from the 2nd row

Comment: `b=$0; gsub(/_/,",",b); print $0 "," b`

Comment: so all this works for the example file with 3 fields (like `a_b_c`), but the moment there are more fields (like `a_b_c_d`) or less fields (like `a_b`), it does not work...

Comment: Please check my EDIT

Comment: OK it works, my files had DOS file ending instead of UNIX, I had to run `dos2unix` on the files first, and now the `awk` one-liner works as expected... weird though

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun here is another `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==1{print "ID,group1,group2,group3"; next}
{s=$0; gsub(/^|_/, ","); print s $0}' file
```

```
ID,group1,group2,group3
a_b_c,a,b,c
d_e_f,d,e,f
g_h_i,g,h,i
```

Comment: for some reason, this works for the example file with 3 fields (like `a_b_c`), but the moment there are more fields (like `a_b_c_d`) or less fields (like `a_b`), it does not work...

Comment: Please check my EDIT

Comment: OK it works, my files had DOS file ending instead of UNIX, I had to run `dos2unix` on the files first, and now the `awk` one-liner works as expected... weird though

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following short `awk` script, combining input from commenters above. It will generate the header line based on the data in the 2nd row - to match the number of fields

```
awk '
NR > 1 {
    n=split($0, a, "_") ;
    if (NR == 2 ) { printf "ID" ; for (i=1 ; i<=n ; i++) printf ",group%d", i ; printf "\n" }
    v=$0
    sub("_", ",", v)
    print $0 "," v
}' filename.txt
```

Comment: this does not seem to work as is, can you provide the full code? cause it might be exactly what I am looking for... thanks!

Comment: Please check my EDIT

Comment: @DaniCee I've added minimal wrapper to execute the program from a shell. It works, as is to process all examples in your question

Comment: I get the following: `awk: calling undefined function gensub
 input record number 2, file in.csv
 source line number 5`

Comment: @DaniCee: `gensub` is standard awk function. What version of awk do you use ? Solution works on Mint 19.04, awk 4.1.4

Comment: I'm on MacOS, `awk --version` gives me `awk version 20070501`

Comment: @DaniCee, this seems to be old version. I do not have a way to test on it. I modified the code to use 'gsub', which should exists in older awk